# SetProperty of "SelectedItem is not supported on control type: Window

Tags: coded-ui-tests

while trying to select an item from combo box in windows application error message showing

> "SetProperty of "SelectedItem" is not supported on control type: Window"

Comment: whats the question?, and please add your code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling an instance of class `Window` but not ComboBox. I see to possible reasons why this happens. Either you are referring to the wrong ui property from `UIMap` or Coded UI Test Builder recorded wrong element or not the whole hierarchy of your wanted test control.

Moreover, if you are trying to select an item in combobox, then just use

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 3; // to select an item by its zero-based index
comboBox.SelectedItem = "Item Text"; // to select an item by its text
```

If it does not help, provide additional information on the problem, particularly on the technology of your Windows Application (UIA/WPF or MSAA/WinForms).